# Nano & Ethernet will not write to PushingBox on a workplace network (but will at home)

Tags: arduino-nano, ethernet, ethernet-shield

I have a Nano+ENC28J60 and I'm using Pushingbox which I have setup to write data to a GoogleDrive spreadsheet which works *perfectly* at home. However when I take it to my workplace it no longer works.

At work, serial tells me that the

- Ethernet connection is good;
- I get a client connection OK too.

*However*, [edit] even with 5 attempts at a response client.read(); it reports nothing at all. Serial shows

```
OK connected! Written. Checking response: + + + + +
```

I assume it is to do with some firewall or other restriction, but if I can get a connection that should be enough, no?

[edit] note: i have also tried connecting to port 443 instead of port 80 in case it was an HTTPS issue - same results, though]

**How I can write to GDrive on my work network?**

The code [edit#2 modified client.connect() to try 5 times and a response check via client.read() to try 5 times and Serial.print("+ "); each time] :

```
#include "DHTesp.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <UIPEthernet.h>

DHTesp dhtA; DHTesp dhtB;     

const int ledPin =  LED_BUILTIN;
int ledState = LOW;
int interval = 20; // this is the num seconds between reads (120=2mins) ***************************
int numReads = 2;   // Amount of reads between posting to Gdocs.  ***************************

byte mac[] = {0xAA, 0xF0, 0xDE, 0xDE, 0x06, 0xAF };  // Ethernet shield MAC addy
byte ip[] = { 10, 10, xx, yy };     
char devid [] = "vXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";  //  device ID from Pushingbox     

char server[] = "http://api.pushingbox.com";
EthernetClient client;

int c = '\0';

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println ();

  Serial.print(F("dB_CoSdataV3.  Establishing..."));
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to configure ethernet"));

    //while (true); // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore
  }
  else {
    Serial.println(F("Ethernet OK."));
    // print the Ethernet board/shield's IP address:
    Serial.print(F("local IP addy: "));
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  }

  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(3000);

  Serial.println("____________________________________________");  Serial.println();

  dhtA.setup(3); //  sensor A
  dhtB.setup(4); //  sensor B
  //dhtC.setup(7); dhtD.setup(7);

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop(){

  int Ahumidity = 0;   int Atemperature = 0 ;
  int Bhumidity = 0;   int Btemperature = 0;

  int j = 0;
  for (j = 1; j <= numReads ; j++ ) {
    int p = 0;
    for (p = 1; p <= interval ; p++) {
      delay (1000);
      // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
      if (ledState == LOW) {        ledState = HIGH;       }
      else {        ledState = LOW;      }
      Serial.print (F("."));
      digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
    }

    Serial.print (" reading: ");
    Ahumidity += 10 * dhtA.getHumidity();  Atemperature += 10 * dhtA.getTemperature();
    Bhumidity += 10 * dhtB.getHumidity();  Btemperature += 10 * dhtB.getTemperature();

    Serial.print (j);     Serial.print (F("/"));     Serial.print (numReads);
    Serial.println();
  }

  Serial.print (F("Show the averaged val.s : "));
  Serial.print(F("\t\tA:")); Serial.print(Atemperature/(numReads)); Serial.print(F("\t")); Serial.print(Ahumidity/(numReads));
  Serial.print  (F("\tB:")); Serial.print(Btemperature/(numReads)); Serial.print(F("\t")); Serial.print(Bhumidity/(numReads));


  // now connect + write to Gdrive....................
  boolean connected;
  int counter1 = 0;
  do {
      connected = client.connect(server, 80);
      if (connected) { break; }
      client.stop();
      delay(1000);
      Serial.println("retry");
      counter1++;
  } while (!connected && counter1 <5);


//------------------
//if (client.connect(server, 80)) {

if (connected){
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print(F("OK connected! "));   

      String buf;

      buf += F("GET /pushingbox?devid=");
      buf += String(devid);

      buf += F("&tempA=");  buf += String(Atemperature/numReads);
      buf += F("&tempB=");  buf += String(Btemperature/numReads);
      buf += F("&tempC=0&tempD=0&tempE=0&tempF=0&tempG=0&tempH=0"); // null data needed

      buf += F("&humidA=");  buf += String (Ahumidity/numReads);
      buf += F("&humidB=");  buf += String (Bhumidity/numReads);
      buf += F("&humidC=0&humidD=0&humidE=0&humidF=0&humidG=0&humidH=0"); //null data needed



      buf += F("&submit=Submit");
      buf += F(" HTTP/1.1");
      //client.println(F("Host: api.pushingbox.com"));
      buf += F("Host: http://api.pushingbox.com"); // trying the addition of http://...
      buf += F("Connection: close\r\n");
      //client.println();

      client.print(buf);
      Serial.print(F(" Written. "));
      delay(1000);   
      int counter2 = 0;
      Serial.print ("Checking response: ");

      do {
          if (client.available()) {
              Serial.print("Y ");
              c = client.read();
              Serial.print((char)c);
          }         
          delay(2000);
          Serial.print("+ ");
          counter2++;
      } while (counter2 < 5);

      Serial.println ();       Serial.println ();
      //client.stop();     
  }


}
```

Comment: You should probably ask your local network administrator.  They are going to be the ones who know how they are blocking you.  You have given us absolutely zero information on the corporate network so there is very little chance of us being able to help you circumvent it.

Comment: sure, thanks @Delta_G. i'm happy to provide whatever information i can - what question should i ask the network administrator?

Comment: you use static IP?

Comment: Hi @ Juraj do you mean the question to ask is: "do we use a static IP here"? if yes/no what would that mean for the sketch? thx

Comment: I asked because you have `byte ip[] = { 10, 10, xx, yy };` but I see `ip` is not used

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I meant.  Your fundamental problem isn't a problem with the Arduino code, it is a problem with the network at work.  You need to ask the network admins there to help you fix the network setting so that your device can connect.  They know what they're doing that's blocking you so they could unblock you.

Comment: you don't use available to check if the response is incoming. read returns -1 if nothing is available. See WiFiClient example on how to wait for the response and copy it to Serial Monitor

Comment: after next edit: if the server doesn't respond at all, connection is blocked. it is some restriction in the network at work

Answer (score 1):

Your code for HTTP request has multiple issues.

After you connect to an HTTP server, it doesn't send anything until it receives your request. Your check for available bytes should always fail. Remove the `if (client.available())` part, including the `else` part.

You make a POST request, but you put all parameters to URL and the request has no body. Change it to GET or put the parameters into request body and use "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded". Don't forget the Content-length parameter.

You send the request in very small parts. Every single print is send right away over network. Concatenate strings and print one or use buffered print.

And you should read the HTTP response and check the status.

Comment: some reading to content length and buffering https://github.com/jandrassy/StreamLib/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks Juraj. i have 1. changed POST to GET (as it should have been:) 2. concatenated the separate client.print statements as a string and now client.print all in one go. Unfortunately same result :(  A question: where/how do i  read HTTP response? cheers

Comment: FYI i tried char c = client.read (); Serial.print (c); after the all-in-one client.print, and i get a backwards '?'

Comment: FYI#2 i also tried if (client.connect(server, 443) { in case it was a HTTPS issue... gives exactly the same results :(

Comment: see WebClient on example how to prin response. use available()

Comment: Thx Juraj. as i said in the comment above i just get a backwards '?' on the response. nothing else

Comment: add to code in Question the response read

Comment: you don't use available to check if the response is incoming. read returns -1 if nothing is available. See WiFiClient example on how to wait for the response and copy it to Serial Monitor/

Comment: code edited to incorporate @Juraj suggestions. Same result :( Any ideas from here?

Comment: if the server doesn't respond at all, connection is blocked. it is some restriction in the network at work

Comment: OK. i was really hoping to avoid IT who will just say "NO" because its easier for them.  Excuse the N00B question but would work WiFi end up at the exact same blockage?

Comment: it is not common to block port 80, so it will be something about known and temporary IP addresses. at my work we have a WiFi for guests which has Internet access but not intranet access